# how to filter object by localDateTime in java spring boot?

Tags: java, filter, java-8

I have object, this is describe of it?

```
public MemberSkills(User user, BasicSkills skills, Short level, Short status, LocalDateTime confirmDate, String comment) {
    this.user = user;
    this.skills = skills;
    this.level = level;
    this.status = status;
    this.confirmDate = confirmDate;
    this.comment = comment;
}
```

I want to filter MemberSkill by from "confirmDate" to "confirmDate".
I am using Java-8 & Java-springboot.
I tried, but it did not work.

```
LocalDateTime fromdate = LocalDateTime.parse(memberSkillRequest.getFromDate(), formatter);
LocalDateTime toDate = LocalDateTime.parse(memberSkillRequest.getToDate(), formatter);

List<MemberSkills> filterMemberSkill = memberSkills.stream().filter(memberSkill -> memberSkill.getConfirmDate().isBefore(fromdate)).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<MemberSkills> listMemberSkill = filterMemberSkill.stream().filter(memberSkill -> memberSkill.getConfirmDate().isAfter(toDate)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

fromdate and todate get from client send up.

Comment: You have a `MemberSkills` object. Now, what do you mean by `filter` it?

Comment: In MemberSkills object contain attribute confirmDate, I want to filter by confirmDate?

Comment: `isBefore(fromdate)` seems backwards. Don't you want *after* the _from_ date and *before* _todate_

Comment: What is the main problem? Do you get an empty list? Or does the list contain the wrong objects?

Comment: sorry, because I don't understand about filter so I don't use it and how it use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you are running second filtering on the first filtered list which already excluded anything comes out of the second filter. You should be able to do something like this -

```
List<MemberSkills> filterMemberSkill = memberSkills.stream()
                 .filter(memberSkill -> memberSkill.getConfirmDate().isBefore(toDate) 
                                   && memberSkill.getConfirmDate().isAfter(fromDate))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: *Because*... the filter in the question included the dates in an inverse manner. It included `toDate` where it should've been `fromDate` and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks, in addition to this way, we can use query from DAO to get data, it will to increase performance

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you intended this:

```
    List<MemberSkills> listMemberSkill = memberSkills.stream()
            .filter(memberSkill -> ! memberSkill.getConfirmDate().isBefore(fromdate))
            .filter(memberSkill -> memberSkill.getConfirmDate().isBefore(toDate))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This gives you the `MemberSkills` objects with confirmation dates in the half-open interval between from date and to date. That is, dates have to be *on or after* from date and *strictly before* to date. This is the common way to define time intervals. In the code I use “not before” to mean “on or after”.

Comment: The code has been tested and worked, @nullpointer. What is correct of course depends on what the desired outcome is, which is unclear from the question. “Not before from date but before to date” is not inherently incorrect. I put it there on purpose. And at least *tried* to explain why.

Comment: Alright. On the second look, its the inverse check of [what this answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54233795/1746118). Which IMHO relates more to *filter MemberSkill by from "confirmDate" to "confirmDate"*.

Comment: The functional difference between the two answers is small, just lies on the border: That answer requires the confirmation date to be *strictly after* from date. I just require it to be *on or after* from date. The asker should pick according to the requirements. @nullpointer

Comment: True and agreed.